# DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed [ClickHouse]

Tags: clickhouse

I Create CH with 1 shard and create some db and tables then i change my cluster to have 2 shard. shard 2 started and have all of tables but when i use this query i get error:

SELECT hostname()
FROM tutorial.visits_all

Received exception from server (version 21.3.20):
Code: 516. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Received from chi-repl-05-replicated-0-0:9000. DB::Exception: default: Authentication failed: password is incorrect or there is no user with such name.

I'm sure my password is correct and i use this command clickhouse-client -h clickhouse-repl-05.rezvani-prom.svc --password qwerty  --query "select hostname() from tutorial.visits_all"

Can anyone help me please

Thank you

Comment: this message is from the Distributed table. It cannot connect to another server. Shards use `default` user by default to connect to each other. You can configure `secret` in `remote_servers` or another user/password pair.

Comment: @DennyCrane I think this is from set password for default user. I say that because when i remove password my query works.

Comment: yes. It's expected. Use host_regex and remove password https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+host_regexp

Comment: @DennyCrane What is the best way in k8s?

Comment: host_regexp in case of operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Distributed queries use default user to connect to other shards.
There are options

1. remove password from default user and setup < network > restriction for default user.
2. setup password for default user and use the same password in remote_servers
3. setup < secret > for remote_servers
4. setup another user and use this user in remote_servers
5. host_regexp in case of operator

https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+host_regexp